# Using files as stdin and stdout for subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin

How do I replicate the following batch command using python subprocess module?

```
myprogram < myinput.in > myoutput.out
```

In other words, how do I run `myprogram` using the contents of `myinput.in` as the standard input and `myoutput.out` as standard output?

Answer (score 47):

The following should work:

```
myinput = open('myinput.in')
myoutput = open('myoutput.out', 'w')
p = subprocess.Popen('myprogram.exe', stdin=myinput, stdout=myoutput)
p.wait()
myoutput.flush()
```

Comment: This looks close to what I need. How do I detect if errors occurred?

Comment: Nevermind. stderr=subprocess.PIPE, then, if stderr: print error

Comment: In the line `myoutput = open('myoutput.out'. 'w')` parameters should be separated by a `,`, not a `.`

Comment: While this answer remains correct, note that [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), added in Python 3.5, is a nicer API for the majority of `subprocess` use cases. It similarly takes `stdin` and `stdout` keyword arguments.