# Standard input inconsistency between command line and subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I would like to create a file that will be used as standard input for a python script, and invoke said script with subprocess.call.

When I do it directly in the command line it works fine:

The input file:

```
# test_input
1/2/3
```

The python script

```
# script.py
thisDate = input('Please enter date: ').rstrip()
```

The following command works just fine:

```
python script.py < test_input
```

But when I try to do the following from within another python script, it doesn't work. (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167603/python-using-files-as-stdin-and-stdout-for-subprocess))

```
outfile1 = open('test_input', 'w')
outfile1.write('1/2/3')
outfile1.close()

input1 = open('test_input')
subprocess.call(['python', 'script.py'], stdin=input1)
```

But then I get the following error:

```
>>>thisDate = input('Please enter date: ').rstrip()
>>>AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

When I did some debugging, it seems that it is getting the integer 0 as the input.

What is causing the inconsistency here? Are the two methods not equivalent (evidently they are not, but why)? My ultimate goal is to perform the exact same task as the above command line version that worked.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a Python 2 vs. Python 3 issue. In Python 2, `input` will evaluate the string as two integer divisions before returning the result; you would usually use `raw_input` instead. In Python 3, `input` behaves like (and replaces) `raw_input`.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I will reflect my solution in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `input` when it should be `raw_input`, `input` in python2 will `eval` the string. If you run the script with `python3` it will work as is, for `python2` change to `raw_input`.

Using `check_call` is usually a better approach and using `with` to open your files.

```
import subprocess
with open('test_input') as input1:
    subprocess.check_call(['python3', 'script.py'], stdin=input1)
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I definitely wanted to do it in 3. I should have specified in the question.

Comment: @Malonge,I would also recommend using `check_call`. It will raise a CalledProcessError for a non-zero exit status. Also use `with` to open your files.

Answer (score 0):

So chepner was correct. When I amended the following line:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'script.py'], stdin=input1)
```

to:

```
subprocess.call(['python3', 'script.py'], stdin=input1)
```

it worked just fine.

(I am trying to do this in python3)

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, the file has two lines, and `input()` reads and parses the first line, which is a comment.

In the second case, the comment line is missing, so Python reads and parses a number.

You probably meant to use `raw_input()`, or run the script with Python 3.

(You probably also meant for the input file to end with a newline, and it doesn't really make sense to use `subprocess.call()` to run Python when you are already running Python.)

Answer (score 0):

`python script.py < test_input` command should fail. You might mean: `python3 script.py < test_input` instead due to the difference between `input()` vs `raw_input()` on Python 2 as mentioned in other answers. [`python` as a rule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) refers to Python 2 version.

if the *parent* script is run only using `python3` then you could use `sys.executable` to run the child script using the same `python` version (the same executable):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

with open('test_input', 'rb', 0) as input_file:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable or 'python3', 'script.py'],
                          stdin=input_file)
```

If the parent and the child may use different python versions then set the correct shebang in `script.py` e.g., `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and run the script directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

with open('test_input', 'rb', 0) as input_file:
    subprocess.check_call(['./script.py'], stdin=input_file)
```

Here, the child script may choose its own python version. Make sure the script has executable permissions: `chmod +x script.py`. Note: Python Launcher for Windows understands the shebang syntax too.

Unrelated: use `.communicate()` instead of `outfile1.write('1/2/3')`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(['./script.py'], stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    p.communicate('1/2/3')
```